# How to use dexlib2 to create a new method

Tags: android, dex

I know we can use Rewriter to modify an existing method. How can we create a new method to add to the dex file? Can anyone give a simple example?

Comment: I found some code that adds a field to a class. I would assume that adding a method should work similar: https://github.com/alibaba/atlas/blob/c20c5b83f67b9a14fb597d59a287ec7a3e5bdbac/atlas-gradle-plugin/dexpatch/src/main/java/com/taobao/android/tools/PatchFieldTool.java#L492-L529